# CreateFile - dwDesiredAccess

Tags: c, winapi, bitflags

As said here [Microsoft docs - CreateFileA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea)

> `dwDesiredAccess`
>
> The requested access to the file or device, which can be summarized as
>   read, write, both or neither zero).
>
> The most commonly used values are GENERIC_READ, GENERIC_WRITE, or both
>   (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE)

When using both READ and WRITE permissions, why is it written  `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` and not `GENERIC_READ && GENERIC_WRITE`? 
Does the `|` has anything to do with the bitwise OR operator? if yes, why do we use that instead of `&&`?

Comment: `&&` is different to `&`.

Comment: BTW: How about reading a tutorial about bitwise and logical operators in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GENERIC_READ` and `GENERIC_WRITE` are bit flags - values that only have one bit set. To combine them you use the bitwise or operator `|`. `&&` is not a bitwise operator, but a logic operator.